# Selenium WebDriver click label with InternetExplorerDriver in Compatibility Mode

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

Has anyone ever succeeded clicking a label while debugging (i.e. IE is not focused) on an intranet or "compatibility view"-enabled site? I've tried every combination of `EnableNativeEvents`/`RequireWindowFocus`/`EnablePersistentHover` I could think of (with `RequireWindowFocus` just hanging the browser), bar sending a js snippet to click nothing works.

Here `Process.Start` simulates loosing focus, e.g. when hitting a breakpoint.

Windows 7 x64, IE 10 x86, WebDriver 2.33.0.0, IEDriverServer Win32 2.33.0

```cs
[Test]
public void CompatibilityViewLabel()
{
    var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
    {
        EnableNativeEvents = false,
        //RequireWindowFocus = true,
        //EnablePersistentHover = true,                
    };

    var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_label");

    var filter = (byte[])Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData").GetValue("UserFilter");
    if (filter == null || !Encoding.Unicode.GetString(filter).Contains("w3schools.com"))
        Assert.Fail("Click Compatibility View icon and retest.");

    driver.SwitchTo().Frame("iframeResult");
    var input = driver.FindElement(By.Id("male"));
    var label = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("label[for='male']"));

    Process.Start("cmd");

    label.Click();
    //driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", label);

    Assert.IsTrue(input.Selected);
}
```

Comment: `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` ....pointless to debug anything until you get this fixed. Have you or can you set your protected mode settings?

Comment: @Arran Why? because it was word "instability" in it? Test fails with or without it, IIRC protected mode and compatibility mode are not related. Edited it out to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Because of http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html.

Comment: @Ardesco interesting read, thank you, I wonder how Coded UI tests get around this problem. In any case I don't have UAC on build agents so tests run under admin and don't mix internet/intranet boundaries, but I'll stop the bad practice. Wonder if I can write and little lib that sets/resets protected mode transparently to the tester...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitted a bug at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5977 and sample page at http://jsbin.com/ijaqog

Answer (score 0):

That page is malformed, it has two body elements and the element you are trying to find is in the second body.  Try it with a different page.

Comment: Selenium, which works with DOM not not-well-formed-by-definition HTML source (SGML vs XML), finds the element and "clicks" it (no NoSuchElementException), click just doesn't register with corresponding input. w3schools is a public example of an label I'm trying to click, in reality it's an intranet site with Compatibility Mode settings enforced by a group policy.

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,5));
wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Id("male"));
```

before label.click();

Comment: The elements is not missing, it is found, it is clicked, no NoSuchElementException is thrown. The problem is that act of "clicking" a label in IE in Compatibility Mode is not registered, the corresponding input is not selected. Without EnableNativeEvents or with it but without focus click does nothing.